# How to make notifications work in Trello

Tags: trello, notifications

I have my notifications set to email instantly.  I have assigned myself to every card in all my lists.  I have due dates on some cards.  Why am i not getting any emails with a summary of due cards?  I thought that got released in Oct 12???

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are sent only to other members - not to the one who makes changes. You need at least two accounts to test them.

Answer (score 0):

You should get notifications about each card when its due date is 24 hours away if you are subscribed to that card.  Unfortunately, the 24 hours is not configurable.